# Who was the real "Master Code Breaker"?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In *The Last Jedi*, Finn and Rose are tasked with finding "the master code breaker" by Maz. They travel to the city of Canto Bight and after searching

> think they found him by the unique lapel pin he wears.

However, they are then apprehended by the local security and thrown into jail where they meet

> another character (played by Benicio del Toro, I think the character is DJ?) who seems to fit the role of master code breaker based on his actions.

Then later once aboard the First Order ship

> DJ betrays Finn and Rose by selling them out. Which seems out of character for someone loyal to Maz.

So my question is who was the "real" master code breaker that Maz has told Finn and Rose about? The one they thought (based on lapel pin) or the one they actually ended up with?

Comment: This seems pretty unclear

Comment: The answers below are comprehensive, but I will share my *speculation*: I suspect DJ is the actual Master Code-Breaker, and he used to be the owner of the lapel pin. But the lapel pin was somehow stolen (or lost) and ended up with the player in the casino. Again, just speculation, we won't know for sure till Episode IX.

Comment: @Sam I was thinking the same thing... that DJ would say "Oh yeah lost that pin in a bet". Hence this question.

Comment: _That_ would be some hell of a coincidence, no? Whereas, randomly finding a code-breaker who is 'good enough' to get the job done is well within the themes of the movie.

Comment: I've protected this question since it seems to have attracted a number of worthless answers from drive-by users.

Comment: @Möoz It's also a hell of a coincidence that on a whole planet, Luke crashes his X-wing within walking distance of Yoda. Don't they hand-wave it as "the will of the Force" or something?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The real Master Codebreaker is a genuine person, at least according to the film's [Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary). His true identity is apparently concealed behind layers of (unbreakable?) encryptions but there's no reason to assume that he isn't who he says he is or that he can't do the things he claims to be able to achieve.

> MASTER CODEBREAKER
>
> Known only by his intriguing title. Master Codebreaker keeps his real
>   identity a secret. He has posted his personal data in a public network
>   node, wrapped in quantum-spread biohexacrypt code. It is an open
>   invitation: anyone who can crack his code is welcome to take over the
>   mantle of Master Codebreaker. To date, no one has come close. The
>   Canto Casino only lets the Codebreaker play dice games and forbids him
>   from any electronic forms of  entertainment.

[image]

---

By comparison, DJ is merely a skilled slicer. He's not in the same league as the Master Codebreaker but he does possess sufficient knowledge of the First Order to be able to get them into the ship

> but insufficient knowledge to get them into the highly guarded vault at the end of their journey

[image]

Comment: Regarding your final note in spoiler tags, I believe it's BB-9E's intervention that prevents that outcome, not DJ's skill level.

Comment: Bio-hexacrypt-protected data networks. Uhu.

Comment: @Mast - I noticed that. Apparently the Master Codebreaker's details are behind a *quantum-spread* bio-hexacrypt code.

Comment: Maz said that “only” a master codebreaker could get them onto the star destroyer - not that merely any skilled slicer could do so.

Comment: @RalphJ : Maz may have been oversimplifying as a result of compressed time for an answer...

Comment: It does seem odd that Maz claims she knows of only one person who can do it yet Finn and Rose stubble upon another random guy who apparently can also do it.

Comment: @MattBurland - Based on them getting caught, I see no good reason to assume that he can do it

Comment: @MattBurland Actually Maz said she only knew one person that she trusted to do it, not that there was only one person capable of it.

Comment: Typo: "to take **e**ver the mantle" instead of "to take **o**ver the mantle".

Comment: Just seeing this question / answer now.  The part about DJ reads strangely.  You mention that he got Rose and Finn aboard Snoke's ship, but then say that he wasn't skilled enough to get them into the "highly-guarded vault" (which was the power breaker access point for the active tracker).  That's not at all what happened in the film.  He did get them inside the access point, but as jeffronicus tried to tell you, BB-9E had already spotted their unusual activity and so a small garrison was awaiting them inside the vault.  Have you seen this scene or are you relying on secondary material?

Comment: @Praxis - That entire sequence completely baffled me. There simply wasn't time for him to sell them out. And why would they agree to give him a pile of cash in return for info when they could just beat it out of him? And how did they even know Finn and Rose's likely destination? And if they were detected because BB-8 had the world's shittest disguise, why then was he left uncaptured? The whole thing struck me as a setup by DJ.

Comment: @Valorum: Good points. Also, earlier in the film (on Canto Bight) I wondered why they imprisoned Finn and Rose but left BB-8 to do as he pleased.

Comment: @Praxis - I presumed that was because BB-8, along with other rebel-programmed droids, has an unusually high level of autonomy.

Comment: @Praxis, it's ambiguous: either DJ was pretending to have given up and then "voila!" the door opened as he knew it was going to. Or he was admitting defeat and then (to his surprise) the door was opened, but by the security team on the inside who were about to get them...