# In The Last Jedi, how did DJ know the plan?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In The Last Jedi, the slicer, DJ, is

> thanked for and paid by, the First Order for telling them the Resistance plan to escape the cruiser using the cloaked ships.

But how did he know about them?

> Finn and Rose didn't know.  Poe, who was in contact with them didn't know.  So how did DJ know?

Comment: Related but not a dup: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176690/how-could-the-first-order-see-the-resistance-ships-at-the-end-of-the-last-jedi/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## He overheard Finn and Poe talking about them.

Before Poe starts his mutiny, he radios Finn to inform him that Vice Admiral Holdo is planning to flee the cruiser and head to the surface and they need to get the tracker down ASAP to make the jump to hyperspace. During this scene, DJ is sat in a chair behind Finn listening to the whole conversation, the film even makes a point of cutting to his face showing him looking interested.

This is foreshadowed earlier in the film when Finn and DJ are finding out who the ship belongs to and they discover it was an Arms dealer selling to both the Resistance and the First Order, DJ talks about how there is no good or bad, merely that people are looking to make a profit.

Comment: So DJ knew from Poe that they were going to be fleeing, and then based on that info, the First Order decided to scan for cloaked ships in that area?  Meaning that cloaked ships can be found, but are not normally scanned for?  Feels like the first order had a hell of a lot of firepower there to not be scanning... need better leadership :P

Comment: Well like Poe, they most likely thought "Go to that salt planet and die, they'll try to get something happening but we're just going to catch them". The Resistance knew (well Leia knew) that there was a base on Crait, so getting to it would be a good idea.

Comment: I read somewhere that Crait was so old and barren that it fell of all public space maps - so maybe the first order didn't even have it on record as a hospitable planet with air, water and anything you need to survive. - They could care less if some rebels crashed on a dead planet without any means of getting off it, and without hyperdrive-capability none of them could have left this dead and forgotten system. - This means the important information was that there is something on Crait that makes an escape worthwhile...

Comment: @Falco, exactly right, I believe that information is taken from the Visual Dictionary.

Comment: @Falco I may be misremembering, but didn't they even say the planet was uncharted in the movie?

Comment: @delinear could be possible, but I don't remember the exact scene where details about Crait where discussed. But I remember that the first order didn't know about Crait being a viable option to regroup.

Comment: @delinear fallen off chart records, it was charged but forgotten

Comment: This is also the answer to the oft-aired question/complaint of "why didn't Holdo just tell everyone what her plan was and eliminate the need for the entire Finn/Poe sideplot?".  You don't do that with any plan that requires secrecy/deception in order to work, because the more people there are that know about it, the more people there are who can leak your plan to your enemy (with or without intending to do so).  I think the proper military term is "compartmentalization".

Comment: Good catch, I've seen it twice and this was still bugging me.

Comment: @aroth, saying "I know you don't trust me, but I *do* actually have a plan" wouldn't have hurt though...

Comment: @Benjol this definitely took a second viewing for me to catch. Although my first viewing, in all honesty, was just me trying to find things to ask for Winter Bash